# python-whois , difference between python 2.7.6 and 2.7

Tags: python, whois

I have bellow function running on Python 2.7.6 and python 2.7.5

This is 2.7.6

```
[root@NMCT-MSL-116-1 python_whois-0.2-py2.6.egg-info]# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep 26 2014, 13:25:30)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import whois as wh
>>> wh.whois('199.96.57.7').emails
['mathew@twitter.com', 'sleibrand@twitter.com', 'noc@twitter.com', 'sconnor@twitter.com',   
'rjohnson@twitter.com', 'fawad@twitter.com', 'net-abuse@twitter.com']
```

This is 2.7.5

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import whois as wh
>>> wh.whois('199.96.57.7').emails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whois/__init__.py", line 11, in whois
domain = extract_domain(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whois/__init__.py", line 35, in extract_domain
return socket.gethostbyaddr(url)[0]
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

It is same code 2 different Centos versions. First one is 6.5, custom python installation of 2.7.6. Second one is Centos 7 and 2.7.5 default installation.  When i manually check both servers can find this host with whois cli tool.

I got stuck and I could not find what is the difference between both machines. They are based on same Network subnet, using same network config except IP addresses.

Does this a difference between versions ? Does anybody has an idea about this ?

Comment: What whois library are you using?

Comment: python-whois  [link](https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/)

Comment: "unknown host" means a name resolution problem, outside of `whois` specifics. did you try to do the whois query manually on the second machine? do you have DNS resolution working perfectly there?